# Cannot connect to SQL Server when browser and protocols are already enabled

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've just reimaged a windows 10 box and installed SQL Server 2012 Management tools, client tools and it has its own SQL Server which works fine.

I'm trying to connect SSMS or Odbcad32 to a SQL Server instance on another machine on the same domain and both SSMS and Odbcad32 won't connect.

Odbcad32 gives this error message:

```
SqlState: '01000'
SQL Server Error:67
Connection Failed:
SqlState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17

SQL Server does not exist or access denied
```

The SQL Server browser is already started. Client protocols are all on for both 32 and 64 bit. i.e. shared memory, TCPIP and named pipes are all enabled, in that order.

I've googled a million threads on this topic and they all seem to find resolution when one of the two above paragraphs are satisfied, but not in this case.

Any other machine can connect to that SQL Server fine.

I can ping it fine.

Changing the SQL Server computer name to the ip address doesn't help, it still won't connect.

The remote server has an instance name of `sql2008`, which I am obviously including when I connect in the form `machinename\sql2008`.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: connecting via Windows auth or SQL Server auth is the same. I am logged in to Windows as `domain\administrator`. UAC is off on this box.

Comment: Can you connect the the instance locally? if so, are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: Yes, the win10 machine has its own sql server which it can connect to, and the sql2008 box can connect to itself.  Any other machine on the network can connect to the sql2008 box. It seems that the win10 box can't connect to any other sql server except itself. logs coming up..

Comment: Can't see anything in the event log - looking in application and system logs. Not sure if there would be other places to look

Comment: The logs on the SQL Server (2008). Not the windows logs.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm there are no log entries relating to sql on the sql2008 box

Comment: No entries? There should be at least something... Sounds like you're looking in the wrong place. From SSMS you can access to logs my expanding the Server in the object explorer, then Management -> SQL Server Logs -> Current -> **View SQL Server Log** (Right Click dialogue). If there are no connection attempts from your Windows 10 PC, this means that the connect isn't hitting the instance;  a likely cause therefore is the firewall/antivirus is blocking the connection (host or client), your connection string is wrong (client), or TCP/IP isn't enabled/configured correctly on the host server.

Comment: Yes, the last entry in there is 30 minutes before my attempt to connect. It just says "starting up database 'AccountsUSA'"

Comment: Windows firewall is off for both machines

Comment: Protocols for the Sql2008 host box are SharedMemory, Named Pipes and TCPIP enabled in that order, and VIA disabled

Comment: And you said you had the browser enabled? When you select "`<Browse for more...>`" and select Network servers in the Connect Dialogue from SSMS, can you see the server? If not, then that implies it's not running, not configured, or being blocked. if you're positive it's running, then I'd suggest talking to your network team for advice; as it seems the traffic is being blocked.

Comment: Yes this is strange I'm now finding that I can't connect to it from any machine, yet I have been able to for the last 10 years, so my original question is now misleading. No boxes can connect to it

Comment: If no machines can connect to it, it's very likely to either be a configuration error, or a firewall.

Comment: OK I think I have made it work - this is a domain controller, and it seems to have got confused - Windows Firewall was already off for the domain profile. I changed the windows firewall policy to allow all connections for "Private Profile" and "Public Profile" then sql connection started working. I've no idea how this happened, but at least it seems to work now. thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Wait, you're running SQL Server on the same server that's your Domain Controller? I'll be honest, that isn't advisable; generally you should leave your DC to be your DC and that's it. I think (as well) that later versions of SQL Server won't even install on a host that is operating as a DC.

Comment: Its just a dev lab and we never had time or inclination or spare hardware to fix it.. always too many other fires burning. totally agree tho :)

Comment: The following video demonstrates how to connect SQL Server Management studio (SSMS) to a SQL Server - focusing on network communication protocols, the OSI model and security issues. It might give you some ideas on how you can resolve your issue. Make sure you look at the SQL Configuration Manager to make sure the correct networking protocols are "enabled" and not "disabled". Part 2 - Connecting to SQL Server
https://youtu.be/tz5hBLEbOOg